# Build an array from .INI file using PHP

Tags: php, ini

I've my .ini file as follows

```
languages.ini
--------------------
fr = "French"
en = "English"
```

Now, I'd like to read the file and keep the keys and values in the form of an array using PHP. I'm very new to PHP. I hope any one help me in achieving this. This is my following code.

```
     public function GetLanguages()
     {
         $langdir = ISC_BASE_PATH.'/language';
         $skip = Array (
            '.',
            '..',
            'CVS',
            '.svn',
         );
         $langs1 = array();
         $dh = opendir($langdir);
         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {


             if (!is_file($langdir.'/'.$file.'/languages.ini')) {
                 continue;
             }


             $langs1[] = $file;                 
          }
         echo "FileLL:".$file;
          foreach ($langs1 as $key) {
              echo "Store languagesss::".$key."<br>";
          }
          return $langs1;

     }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/parse_ini_file ?

Comment: Not sure if it's a learnign exercise or you're just no aware of [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) :-? You also don't really make a question or explain what's wrong with your current code.

Comment: Done.. I did it.         public function GetStoreFrontLanguages()
         {
             $langdir = ISC_BASE_PATH.'/language/en/store_languages.ini';             
             $langs = array();                         
             $vars = parse_ini_file($langdir);
             foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {                 
                 echo "Key iss::".$key."  Value::".$vars[$key]."<br>";
             }
             
         }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for PHP's ini parse function:

[parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/parse_ini_file)

Just call `$arrayResult = parse_ini_file($path_to_file)`